# C Program: Need to Read Multiple Lines of Input Until EOF and Count Words and Number of Lines

Tags: c, count, eof, words

I am new to C and I am having trouble with this program. I'm trying to read text from stdin until EOF and write to standard output the number of words read and the number of lines of input. A word being defined as any string of characters except whitespace. My problems are (1) when the program has to read the last word in a line, it reads an end of line and not a whitespace so it does not add the word, and (2) when the program has to read multiple lines of input. Do I need to do a nested for loop with fgets to read until != "\n"? I am not sure on that one. Here is what I have right now:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>


int main ()
{
    char previousLetter;
    char line[500];
    int numberOfWords, numberOfLines, length, i;

    while (fgets (line, 500, stdin) != NULL)
    {
        length = strlen(line);
        if (length > 0)
        {
            previousLetter = line[0];
        }
        for (i=0; i <= length; i++)
        {
            if(line[i] == ' ' && previousLetter != ' ')
            {
                numberOfWords++;
            }
        previousLetter = line[i];
        }
       numberOfLines++;
   }
   printf ("\n");
   printf ("%d", numberOfWords);
   printf (" %d", (numberOfWords / numberOfLines));
}
```

Comment: by counting at the beginning of the word instead of counting at the end of the word. http://stackoverflow.com/a/25752972/971127 Also, `numberOfWords, numberOfLines` must initialize to 0.

Comment: You don't need `fgets()` for this. All you really care about is (a) is it whitespace?, and if so (b) is it a newline. Consecutive whitespace should be accounted for as well, so as not to pad the word-count incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

1. `fgets()` stores the line ending character, so you can check that as well to mark an end of word
2. Your code already reads multiple lines of input

Comment: So something like this? :

            if((line[i] == ' ' && previousLetter != ' ') || (line[i] = '\n' && previousLetter != ' ') )

Comment: there will only be 1 newline per call to fgets, think about something simpler

Comment: Would this still work? I am not sure if you mean fgets will get called again after newline or that my code will only read past one newline. The program needs to be able to read multiple lines, so more than one newline. Will this code work for that? Sorry it's late and my brain is not think straight.

Comment: go to sleep then. read fgets reference when you wake up, especially its return value.

Comment: fgets() reads in at most one less than size characters from stream and stores them into the buffer pointed to by  s. Reading stops after an EOF or a newline. If a newline is read, it is stored into the buffer. A terminating null byte ('\0') is stored after the last character in the buffer.


So the newline is stored in the buffer so I should be able to compare it as I wrote right?

Comment: why don't you just try it? it's just a couple of characters to type :)

Answer (score 0):

Why use fgets at all?

```
#include<ctype.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
        int c;
        enum {in, out} state = out;
        int line_count = 0;
        int word_count = 0;
        while( ( c = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF ) {
                if(isspace(c)) {
                        state = out;
                } else {
                        if( state == out )
                                word_count += 1;
                        state = in;
                }
                if( c == '\n')
                        line_count += 1;
        }
        printf( "words: %d\n", word_count );
        printf( "lines: %d\n", line_count );
        return 0;
}
```